# Interface hierarchy in Go

Tags: go

I have a program where multiple types of modules are used, but all the different types of modules share certain methods. I'm trying to build a generic factory that can be reused for the different types of modules, but I'm missing something like interface inheritance or however that would be called in Go.

This is an example that I tried to simplify as good as possible:

There is a generic factory which uses a generic `Module` interface:

```
package main

var (
  modules []Module
)

type Module interface {
  RegisterFlagSet()
  GetName() (string)
}

type Factory struct {
  instances []Module
}

func RegisterModules(modules []Module) {
  modules = modules
}

func (f *Factory) registerFlagSets() {
  for _,inst := range f.instances {
    inst.RegisterFlagSet()
  }
}

func (f *Factory) GetInstance(seek string)(Module) {
  for _,inst := range f.instances {
    if (inst.GetName() == seek) {
      return inst
    }
  }
  panic("cannot find module")
}
```

Then there's a more specific implementation for the module type `Timer`. I'm trying to reuse as much of the factory as possible:

```
package main

import (
  "time"
)

var (
  timer_modules = []Timer{
    // list all the timer modules here
  }
)

type Timer interface {
  Module
  GetTicker() (*time.Ticker)
}

type TimerFactory struct {
  Factory
}

func NewTimerFactory() TimerFactory {
  tfact := TimerFactory{}
  RegisterModules(timer_modules)
  return tfact
}
```

When I try to build that I get this error:

```
timer_factory.go:25: cannot use timer_modules (type []Timer) as type []Module in argument to RegisterModules
```

I don't understand why a variable of `type []Timer` cannot be used as `type []Module` because all the methods of the interface `Module` are also in the interface `Timer`, so they should be compatible or not? Is there a way to make them compatible?

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface gives explanations.
One of the workarounds is to implement a new register function:

```
func RegisterModule(m Module) {
  modules = append(modules, m)
}
```

and invoke the function in a range at the cost of only two more lines:

```
func NewTimerFactory() TimerFactory {
  tfact := TimerFactory{}
  for _, t := range timer_modules {
    RegisterModule(t)
  }
  return tfact
}
```

Comment: what if you use the variadic `...` operator ? so the range loop an be removed?

Comment: `...` behaves the way same with slice and does not work.

Comment: The other way is to introduce reflect, which brings performance lost and code complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Change your declaration of Timer

```
type Timer interface {
  Module
  GetTicker()(*time.Ticker)
}
```

Comment: That appears to make sense, but unfortunately I still get the same `cannot use timer_modules (type []Timer) as type []Module in argument to RegisterModules`

Comment: It does work if I only pass single instances of `Timer`, but it doesn't for a slice of timers `[]Timer`.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly